# cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Couldn't load plugin class: json-pretty with Cucumber Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, bdd

I Am New To java-cucumber. Getting This Error:

```
cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Couldn't load plugin class: json-pretty
```

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: json-pretty

[image: Here is my pom.xml]

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        plugin={"pretty", "html:target/cucumber-htmlreport", "json-pretty:target/cucmber-report.json"})

public class CucumberTest {
//codes
}
```

Comment: Give a try by modifying html:target/cucumber-htmlreport **.html**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you were pretty close.

You need to change the *plugin* definations as follows:

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class) 
@CucumberOptions( plugin={"pretty:target/cucumber-htmlreport.text", "json:target/cucmber-report.json"})

public class CucumberTest { //codes }
```

Comment: Thanks DebanjanB. It Worked. :)